# IO Error when reading /proc/$pid/mem after ptrace

Tags: c, kernel

I'm writing a program to replace a string of bytes in the memory of another process. It needs to be written in C, as my target platform doesn't support any higher level languages.

Initially, rather than jumping straight to memory modification, I'm simply trying to read memory into a buffer, so that I can identify the offset at which the string of bytes resides, such that I can then start to modify it.

I've read every stack overflow question and code example I can find, alongside man pages and some general trial and error. My C is a little rusty, and so this is proving rather challenging. The examples I've read seem to take two differing approaches:

- ptrace_attatch to the target process, use multiple calls to ptrace_peekdata to read (int) sized chunks of memory from offset.

or

- ptrace_attatch, open /proc/pid/mem, and use the offsets outlined in /proc/pid/maps to lseek and read() out a given number of bytes.

Here's my code.

program to attatch to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


printf("Spinning up....\n");
char changeme[6] = "AAAAA";
printf("ready for change....\n");

 getchar();

 printf("changeme is %s\n", changeme);  

    return 0;
}
```

program for dumping memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char mempath[PATH_MAX];

 uintptr_t const address = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);

int waitval = 0;

   pid_t target_process = atoi(argv[1]);
   struct user_regs_struct regs;
   int readbytes = 0;
   if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,target_process,NULL,NULL))
           perror("attach");
     printf("attatched!\n");

     waitpid(target_process, NULL, 0);
     sprintf(mempath, "/proc/%s/mem", argv[1]);
     printf("ready! opening %s\n", mempath);

     int memfd = open(mempath, O_RDONLY);
     printf("memfd = %d\n", memfd);
     char *outbuf = malloc(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
     printf("trying to read %d bytes from offset %lu\n",_SC_PAGE_SIZE,address);

     if (outbuf){
      lseek(memfd, address, SEEK_SET);
      readbytes = read(memfd, outbuf, _SC_PAGE_SIZE);
     if (_SC_PAGE_SIZE == readbytes)
        printf("read success! - %s\n", outbuf);
     else
        printf("readfailed! read %d bytes: %s\n", readbytes, outbuf);
      printf("oh noes! %s\n", strerror(errno));
     free(outbuf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the terminal output:

terminal 1:

```
[10:59] tel0s@Relentless:~/research$ ./changeme 
Spinning up....
ready for change....
```

terminal 2:

```
[11:35] tel0s@Relentless:~/research$ ps aux | grep changeme
tel0s     7763  0.0  0.0   4076   352 pts/2    S+   10:59   0:00 ./changeme
tel0s     8297  0.0  0.0   8948   928 pts/1    S+   11:35   0:00 grep --colour=auto changeme
[11:35] tel0s@Relentless:~/research$ cat /proc/7763/maps
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2260791                            /home/tel0s/research/changeme
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 2260791                            /home/tel0s/research/changeme
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 2260791                            /home/tel0s/research/changeme
7fb2cfc56000-7fb2cfdf7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 4890420                    /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7fb2cfdf7000-7fb2cfff6000 ---p 001a1000 fd:00 4890420                    /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7fb2cfff6000-7fb2cfffa000 r--p 001a0000 fd:00 4890420                    /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7fb2cfffa000-7fb2cfffc000 rw-p 001a4000 fd:00 4890420                    /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7fb2cfffc000-7fb2d0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb2d0000000-7fb2d0022000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 4888842                    /lib64/ld-2.17.so
7fb2d01f2000-7fb2d01f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb2d021e000-7fb2d0221000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb2d0221000-7fb2d0222000 r--p 00021000 fd:00 4888842                    /lib64/ld-2.17.so
7fb2d0222000-7fb2d0223000 rw-p 00022000 fd:00 4888842                    /lib64/ld-2.17.so
7fb2d0223000-7fb2d0224000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff03290000-7fff032b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff03394000-7fff03395000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

[11:36] tel0s@Relentless:~/research$ sudo ./writeprocmem 7763 400000 
attatched!
ready! opening /proc/7763/mem
memfd = 3
trying to read 30 bytes from offset 400000
readfailed! read -1 bytes: 
oh noes! Input/output error
```

My immediate thoughts for possible reasons are:

- I've totally borked my logic, and I'm not using Ptrace correctly.
- My changeme program is in a strange state because of gets() and that's why im failing to read (I tried with an instance of bash, and i had the same output however)
- I'm not casting/using the right type for my offsets, and that's why the read is failing

Any help would be excellent, and I'd rather answers outlined what mistakes I'm making, rather than just giving me working code outright, as I want to understand this fundamentally, not just make my code functional.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the return status of the system calls. If they fail, errno will be set to indicate what went wrong, and you can display the associated text with perror().

E.g. something like:

```
if (lseek(memfd, address, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
   perror("lseek");
}
readbytes = read(memfd, outbuf, _SC_PAGE_SIZE);
if (readbytes < 0) {
   perror("read");
}
```

Roy Hills

Answer (score 1):

```
uintptr_t const address = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);
```

> [11:36] tel0s@Relentless:~/research$ sudo ./writeprocmem 7763 400000

```
printf("trying to read %d bytes from offset %lu\n",_SC_PAGE_SIZE,address);
```

you're telling strtoul that the base is zero, the address from /proc//maps is in hex, you're debug printing it out in decimal. your address unfortunately happened to be a number that's valid both as hex and decimal.

either, use 0x400000 on the command line or tell strtoul to use base 0x10

you also want to use sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE) or getpagesize().